# Problem with Simple dialog box in jquery?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, iframe

I am using simple dialog for showing some custom popup having a iframe in it whose source is a VF page. Below is the code i am using for it in Javascript.

```
 function openDialog(var1,var2){
  if (var1 != null && var2 !=''){

   var pageURL = '/apex/myVFPage?id='+var1 +'&name='+var2;

    var sd = new SimpleDialog("Test", true);

    sd.setTitle("Message From Webpage");

    sd.createDialog();
     window.parent.sd = sd; 
     sd.setWidth("50%");

   //Specify the iFrame and give URL of VF page
    sd.setContentInnerHTML("<iframe src="+pageURL+" style='border:1;wiidth:460px;  min-height: 170px' ></iframe>");

     if ($j(sd.dialog).find('#InlineEditDialogX').size() == 0) {
     var close = $j("<a id='InlineEditDialogX' title='Close' tabindex='0'             href='javascript:void(0)' class='dialogClose'>Close</a>");

    close.mouseover(function() {

       this.className = 'dialogCloseOn';
        }).mouseout(function() {
          this.className = 'dialogClose';
          }).click(function() {

       // finally our on click handler which closes the dialog
        sd.hide();
       });
      // insert the new generated close button before the h2 tag so it'll show up on   the top right corner
    close.insertBefore($j(sd.dialog).find('.topLeft h2'));  
     } sd.show(); 

    }

}
```

I am calling this javascript function from my VF page button.

How can i close the dialog box from my iframe's VF page.  And re-render my parent VF page to new href from the child VF page(i.e. in the iFrame).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the postMessage function from within the iframe to tell the parent to close the dialog, see: http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe

So in your function you would listen for a message from the iframe e.g. "closeMe" then remove the dialog.

Mark